# Sequence of step functions satisfying $\frac{\int^1_0\phi (t)dt}{||\phi_n||_{\infty}}\rightarrow 0 \text{ as $n \rightarrow \infty$}$

Tags: real-analysis, step-function

Is there a sequence of step functions $\phi_n :[0,1] \rightarrow \Bbb R (n \in \Bbb N)$ that satisfy $\int^1_0 \phi_n(t)dt \gt 0$ and $$\frac{\int^1_0\phi_n (t)dt}{||\phi_n||_{\infty}}\rightarrow 0 \text{ as $n \rightarrow \infty$}$$

I can't seem to conceive a function that would satisfy such conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\psi_n(t)=1$ for $t \leq \frac 1  2$ and $-1$ for $t >\frac 1 2$ the $\int_0^{1} \psi_n (t)dt=0$ for all $n$ and $\|\psi_n\|_{\infty}=1$ for all $n$. Now take $\phi_n =\frac  1 n+\psi_n$. Note that $\|\phi_n\|_{\infty}\geq 1-\frac 1 n$.

Comment: but the integral is supposed to be greater than $0$

Comment: @Mavzouleus $\int \phi_n=\frac  1n >0$.

Comment: How is $\psi_n$ going to be $1$ when for example $n=3$ ? Isn't it overlapping with the condition that for $t\leq 1/2$ $\psi_n(t)=1$?

Comment: @Mavzouleus Sorry, there was a typo. My functions  $\psi_n$ do not depend on $n$ at all.

Comment: Ok so let me get this right, for $t \leq 1/2$ $\phi_n= 1/n+1$ and for $t \gt 1/2$ $\phi_n=1/n-1$ so then the integral is $\int^{1/2}_0 1/n+1 dt + \int^1_{1/2} 1/n-1 dt = \frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2n}-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{2}{2n}=\frac{1}{n}$ and $||\phi_n||_{\infty}=2$ so then $\frac{\int^1_0\phi_n(t)dt}{||\phi_n||_{\infty}}=\frac{1/n}{2}\rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ ?

Comment: @Mavzouleus You almost got it right but $\|\phi_n\|_{\infty}$ is not $2$. It is $1+\frac  1 n$. [Even though $\psi_n$ does not depend on $n$, $\phi_n$ does depend on $n$].

Comment: but the maximum value $\phi_n$ can take is $2$? Since max $1+1/n$ is $2$? for $n \in \Bbb N$

Comment: You have to compute $\|\phi_n\|_{\infty}$ for each fixed $n$  before taking the limit as $ n \to \infty$ and not take the maximum value over all $n$.

Comment: Why did you explicitly state " note that $||\phi_n||_{\infty} \gt 1-1/n$" ?

Comment: @Mavzouleus If $a_n >1-\frac  1 n$ then $\frac {1/n} {a_n}\leq \frac 1 {n(1-\frac  1n)} \to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

For $n=1,2,\dots$ define $\phi_n = 1$ on $[0,1/n]$ and $0$ elsewhere. Then for each $n,$ $\phi_n$ is a step function, $\|\phi_n\|_\infty=1,$ and $\int_0^1\phi_n = 1/n.$ We're done.